# My change handler does not work consistently

Tags: javascript

I am using a change handler in my JavaScript that executes after I have tabbed away from the text box. But when I make changes to that text box a second time, the change handler doesn't work. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You might want to post what your current code is, so we can see what's the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem, but `onchange` usually fires after the Element has changed and looses focus. Use `onblur` instead, for the behavior you seek.